# Alexa jumping to stopIntent instead Of AgreeIntent for Australia and Canada Language

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

I have developed My skill and assigned 5 languages to it. US,AU,UK,IN,CA. Everything is working good for the US,UK and India but when it comes to AU and CA, whenever i say yes or no, it fires the stop intent and close the app. Everything is same for all the languages. Please help. My app failed certification for this reason.

My agreeIntent utterances are yes, no, yup, nope and StopIntent utterances are stop, bye, goodbye.

Comment: which intents are triggered when you say "Yes" and "No" ?

Comment: It is triggering StopIntent

Comment: You should ideally use predefiend AMAZON.StopIntent, AMAZON.YesIntent and AMAZON.NoIntent and add your extra utterances accordingly.

Comment: Then why it is working fine with other languages? AND yes I m talking about AMAZON.StopIntent only.

Comment: Hard to tell without your interaction model. But you should not use agreeIntent with utterances both yes and no, instead use AMAZON.YesIntent for "yes" and AMAZON.NoIntent for "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create custom `YesIntent` or `NoIntent`, instead always use predefined `AMAZON.YesIntent` for **"Yes"** and `AMAZON.NoIntent` for **"No"**.

**"Yes"** and **"No"** are logically different, so it will be a good approach to use corresponding predefined intents rather than using `agreeIntent`. If you want to add custom utterances like **"Yup"**, you can add it to `AMAZON.YesIntent` like any other intent.

One issue that you may encounter is while using `ConfirmSlot` or `ConfirmIntent` directive. Here when the user says **"Yes"**, instead of sticking on to the current intent and confirming it, there is chance that Alexa would map the confirmation-**"Yes"** to the custom `YesIntent` and break the directive.